# Passing variable to sass in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm building a small frontend project using react. I made my components to load environment variables from yaml file.

```
...
import '../styles/main.scss';
import site from '../config.yml'

...

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Helmet>
                  <title>{ site.title }</title>
                  <meta
                    name="description"
                    content={ site.description }
                  />
                </Helmet>
...
```

It works well right now, but what I'm stuck with is passing that `site` variable into main.scss file.

```
@import
  "skins/{{ site.text_skin }}",
...
```

Like this, and I have according {{text_skin}}.scss file in the directory.
so far, I couldn't find a way to import yaml file in scss file directly, nor passing json variable to scss file from js file in REACT.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Where is that import line coming from?

Comment: Did you try to import dynamically from your component? `const styles = import(\`skins/${site.text_skin}\`)`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports

Comment: @rrd it's for importing sub style files into main.scss,

`@import
  "skins/{{ site.text_skin }}",
  "components/header",
  "components/footer",
  "skins/default"
;`

Comment: Yes I understand what it's for, but whereabout is it? Is it in your main component? Is it in a sub component?

Comment: @rrd it's in main.scss file, I'm not sure I understood the question properly..

Comment: @soywod thanks, I think it will work that way but I wonder if the value can be used inside the scss file.

Comment: @rrd Ah its from the main component, App.js

Comment: @rokrokss I don't think you will be able to do this in scss